# How to store datatable in redis against a key

Tags: c#-4.0, redis

I am using redis for caching. I have fired a stored procedure on database and converted result into datatable. Now I have to store this datatable in redis cache. Let me know the best way for this.

Comment: Tell us more about the nature of the data.  How large is it?  How is it structured?

Answer (score 0):

Redis provide much more powerful data types for storing data.

You need to look at Hashes, set, List, simple keys , sorted set to find out exactly what data type fits into your requirement.

You should probably know how would you consume this stored data and then choose the best possible data structure that suits/caters your needs.

Here's is a small intro on redis data types
[A fifteen minute introduction to Redis data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned datatable in your question, I am assuming you have data in following format

```
Id name status
 1  XYZ  A
 2  ABC  I
```

If you have data in this format. I will put it into hash. So 1 record = 1 hash

```
HMSET datatable:1 name XYZ status A
HMSET datatable:2 name ABC status I
```

And I will keep the Hash keys in another set

```
SADD datatable:keys 1 
SADD datatable:keys 2
```

Then you can get the keys of all hashes using

```
SMEMBERS datatable:keys
```

After that you can get all the hashes. Make sure you use REDIS pipeline. if you are using redis 2.8 you dont need to use SMEMBERS and and handle it at application level. You can directly use SORT command

```
SORT datatable:keys BY nosort GET datatable:*->name GET datatable:*->status
```

This will give you name and status of datatable:1 and datatable:2

Comment: Actually what I am doing is I am fetching data as datatable then converting each record to a collection of (key,val) pair, then adding each collection in a set against a main key.So ultimately main key set will have its value as a collection.

Comment: Yaa tht will work too but isnt an elegant way. You will lose control of data if you dont put records as hash. Like you wont be able to fetch only few fields. Remembers SETS are random so if you have operation like to fetch first 10 records. Everytime you will fetch new records you will get different records.